# How to cache the base Docker image when using an external CI CD provider

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I am currently using a CI CD provider (gitlab.com) to build docker images (via multi-stage) and then deploy those built images to my server.

The images are very similar between each other, in fact they all use php-apache as a base image; the only thing that changes is the code that I COPY from the repository.

So in theory, the best scenario for disk usage would be for my images to all share the same cached version of php-apache.

However, on my server I can see that the resulting image is always 400MB+, which means that probably the base php-apache is not cached at all.

What can I do to cache the base image php-apache for all of my built images? Ideally, every app container should be of lesser size because they all share the same image.
Is this even possible? Or maybe it is possible but only by building locally instead than on ci cd? Thanks.

Just for clarity, this is a simplified version of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM jitesoft/composer:7.4 AS php_installer
COPY ./ /app
WORDIR app
RUN composer install

FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY --from=php_installer /app/. /var/www/
```

Instead, the gitlab deploy happens via a ci cd script very similar to this
https://caprover.com/docs/ci-cd-integration.html#9--gitlab-ci-file

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are seeing the size of docker images through `docker image list`, this can be misleading as this is the total size needed to install all the layers of the image, what does that mean?

**Layers**

Docker images are not monoliths, instead they are composed of read-only *layers*, which are ways of representing changes on the filesystem. You can see the layers that compose your image by doing:

`docker history <image id>`

Example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN echo "Hi" >> test.txt
```

```
> docker build -t test:latest .
> docker image list 
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
test                    latest              06c4055eba9f        3 minutes ago       132MB
ubuntu                  16.04               f6f49faac5cf        6 days ago          132MB
> docker history 06c4055eba9f
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
06c4055eba9f        3 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c echo "Hi" >> test.txt                3B             
f6f49faac5cf        6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B             
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /run/systemd && echo 'do…   7B             
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*          0B             
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -xe   && echo '#!/bin/sh' > /…   745B           
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:925571658dd8453e5…   132MB
```

Here we can see that this image that contains a file that says Hi (which is three bytes long "Hi\0") consists of two layers. One that is just over 132Mb and one that is 3B.

**Why this matters**

This is the magic of docker! When someone downloads your docker image they only need to download the layers that they don't have! This means that if someone was to download my test:latest image then they would only need to download 3B (assuming they have ubuntu:16.04).

The reason docker presents this 400Mb size to you is because that is the *maximum* size of the download if the user needs to download all the layers of the docker image.

If you want to read more about this here is a documentation page on it:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/

And the key part is:

> Notice that all the layers are identical except the top layer of the second image. All the other layers are shared between the two images, and are only stored once in /var/lib/docker/. The new layer actually doesn’t take any room at all, because it is not changing any files, but only running a command.

Also you should read this article:

https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2018/03/14/docker-image-size.html

**Conclusion**

You don’t have to cache your base image because docker automatically does this for you. It was difficult to see that it was doing it for you though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment (I didn't know about docker history), but I don't think this is happening in my case, infact the way I realized was that my disk was full to 99.9% and I had to do a cleanup with docker purge before being able to start the server again; only after I saw the image size via portainer

Comment: How big is your base image by default and how big is your layer on top of that?

Comment: I think it's approximately 450-500mb the base and 50mb my layer;

this is the docker history: If I am not wrong this is in reverse order and the first 6 ones, before CMD, are the ones that I build; everything after should be the base image
https://pastebin.com/emtzyHPe

Comment: How many images did you have on your server?

Comment: Now I have 5 images that are built on php-apache, before I had a lot more but I don't remember the precise number unfortunately; as a test I tried to build another image and I can confirm that the percentage of my disk usage goes higher as if no caching happens

Comment: Ok so in summary you have 5 images and your disk usage is 5 * 500Mb so 2.5Gb higher than before the images were present? If that is true then I will do some more research because something is going on.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what is happening. I don't know if this could be related to caprover, which I am using to deploy the images. I tried with other images different than php apache and the same problem happens